# React: window.scrollTo(0,0) on component render EACH time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm building a portfolio site with React that I'd like to have mimic the behavior of a typical website. When I click on a particular project, I'm routed to a new URL, however, the position of the scroll bar remains the same as it was on the 'previous' page, EXCEPT for the first time clicking on a project (if I click the back button and click on a new project, the scroll bar is at the same position). I'd like for the window to scroll to the top each time I click on a project.

```
class Project extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let project = this.props.project;
        let linkTo = "/work/" + project.id;

        return (
             <figure>
                <img src={project.thumbnail} />
                <figcaption>
                    <h3>{project.title}</h3>
                    <p>{project.type}</p>
                </figcaption>
                <Link to={linkTo} />
             </figure>
        )
    }
}

export default Project;
```

Clicking on a Project component routes you to "work/:id" which renders the ProjectDetail component.

```
class ProjectDetail extends React.Component {
    // componentDidMount() {
    //  window.scrollTo(0,0);
    // }

    // componentWillUpdate() {
    //  window.scrollTo(0,0);
    // }

    render() {
        // window.scrollTo(0,0);
        let project = PROJECTS.find((item) => item.id == this.props.params.id);
        return (
            <DetailMain project={project} />
        )
    }
}

export default ProjectDetail;
```

So, each time a Project component is rendered, I'd like for the window to scroll to the top. You can see where I've been trying get the scrolling to work.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve my problem using the code provided here: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/2144

```
var history = createBrowserHistory();

history.listen(location => {
  // Use setTimeout to make sure this runs after React Router's own listener
  setTimeout(() => {
    // Keep default behavior of restoring scroll position when user:
    // - clicked back button
    // - clicked on a link that programmatically calls `history.goBack()`
    // - manually changed the URL in the address bar (here we might want
    // to scroll to top, but we can't differentiate it from the others)
    if (location.action === 'POP') {
      return;
    }
    // In all other cases, scroll to top
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  });
});

var routes = (
  <Router history={history}>
    // ...
  </Router>
);
```

This seems to work for now until something gets integrated in react-router.

Comment: u are a king.. ty so much

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [`react-router`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) or [`history`](https://github.com/rackt/history).

**React Router**

```
<Router onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)} history={createBrowserHistory()}>
  // routes
</Router>
```

Found [here](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/2019).

**History**

Use `history.listen` to be notified when the `location` changes.

```
import { createHistory } from 'history';

let history = createHistory();

// Listen for changes to the current location. The
// listener is called once immediately.
let unlisten = history.listen(function(location) {
  console.log(location.pathname);
  // scroll logic here
})

// When you're finished, stop the listener.
unlisten();
```

More about that [here](https://github.com/rackt/history/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The first option partially works. If I click on a project, click 'Back' but don't scroll at all and click on the same or new project, the scrollTo(0,0) doesn't work. However, if I click on a project, click 'Back' and move around on that page and click on the same or new project, everything works. Any ideas on this? Is this because onUpdate is not being called?

Comment: Also, the second option seemed to work. I added an answer.